# What about someone use "receives 6 spam or offensive flags:−100" rule?

Tags: discussion, reputation, spam, trolling, penalty

What if a bunch of jealous bad guys just want to interfere with SE Community and they decide to cast 6 spam flags on an innocent person? Will the poor guy lose 100 hard earned reputations?

Comment: Presumably if it clearly wasn't spam a moderator or the SE team could reverse it if you contacted them. We should test it on this question ;-).

Comment: @PeterJ _Come at me, bro!_

Comment: Related: [What if six users conspire to nuke posts with spam flags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223297/223030)

Comment: @michaelb958 No, Sir, that's different. I just want to know if this"-100 reputation"penalty is done by the system without approval of an moderator.

Comment: Yes, it's done automatically when six spam/offensive flags are cast.

Comment: @ave when people say "related" they aren't saying it's a duplicate, just a related question. That said; in this case it is strongly related, perhaps even a duplicate

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Thanks for telling me that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for six users to misuse spam flags in this way. The reputation penalty is automatically applied once the 6th flag is cast.

But this is also something that would lead to an immediate and rather harsh reaction by a moderator, followed by reversing the deletion and the -100 reputation penalty caused by the malicious flags.

Comment: You sure undeleting the post really reverse the penalty i.e. give the 100 points back?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Undeleting doesn't give back the -100 reputation, but the "clear spam flags" tool in the mod menu does.

Comment: Oh, nice mod tool!

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Yep :)